# mostar y ocultar elementos

Tags: javascript

quisiera que me puedan ayudar, necesito saber si es posible realizar esto o solo estoy perdiendo el tiempo.  Necesito ocultar/mostrar ciertos campos que son unos combobox, yo se que se pueden ocultar o mostrar  al seleccionar un checkbox o un combobox, pero necesito saber si se puede realizar a traves de un inputs name, en realidad si también se puede, pero cuando quiero recargar la pagina y modificar la información el campo input que yo traigo con un valor X no hace nada. Cuando empiezo a escribir mi formulario tengo un input edad y segun la edad me aparecen dos campos ocultos, hasta ahi todo bien, pero cuando modifico la misma información no hace nada si la edad ingresada anteriormente venía visible.  Tengo el siguiente código con el que estoy trabajando.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("input[name='edad']").change(function() {
    if($(this).val()>4){
        $("#est").fadeIn();
        $("#act").fadeIn();
    }else{
        $("#est").fadeOut();
        $("#act").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Te refieres a que al cargar la página si hay texto por default en el input no realiza las acciones?

Comment: Exactamente, es como que no refresca la info de la edad y no ejecuta la acción de mostrarse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque solo realiza eso cuando hace el change, tienes que ponerlo también en el document ready

```
$(document).ready(function (){
if($("input[name='edad']").val()>4){
        $("#est").fadeIn();
        $("#act").fadeIn();
    }else{
        $("#est").fadeOut();
        $("#act").fadeOut();
    }
$("input[name='edad']").change(function() {
    if($(this).val()>4){
        $("#est").fadeIn();
        $("#act").fadeIn();
    }else{
        $("#est").fadeOut();
        $("#act").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Si lo quieres hacer más limpio crea eso en una función y mándala a llamar en ambos casos.

Answer (score 0):

A tu input agrégale una clase la que tu quieras puede ser `.inputChange` y agrega esto al final de tu JS después de que los valores ya se cargaron en tu input :

```
$(".inputChange").change();
```

Si van a ser mas de 1 input puedes agregarles a todos los que necesites la misma clase y agregar esto al final en lugar de lo anterior.

```
$(".inputChange").each(function(){
 $(this).change();
});
```

Esto hará que ejecute la función `change()` de todos los elementos que necesites

Espero te sirva.